# Does HashMap's equals depend on EntrySet.keySet?

Tags: java, hashmap, equals

I have a Java Object, where I have overridden the `equals()` method for comparing all values. One of the member variables that I compare is a `HashMap<String, MyObject>`. Even if the keys and MyObjects stored in there are equal, the HashMaps seem not to be.

When I debug my tests and take a look into both HashMaps, I can see that the `EntrySet`s are not equal. But the only difference I can see in them is that one has a `EntrySet.keySet` being **null**, and the other having the Entry.keySet being a `KeySet` object.

My question now is: does the `equals()` method of HashMap depend on this value or not?

*(I don't want you to help me debug my code, I just want to understand what is happening)*

Comment: Have you written an `equals()` method for `MyObject`?

Comment: Yes, and if I check the contained `MyObject`s outside the HashMap, they are equal.

Comment: I think this question is unanswerable until you show how these maps are instantiated and populated. Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: The `equals()` method calls `entrySet()`, which returns a `Set<Map.Entry<K,V>`, and checks whether those `Set`s are equal. See [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29). If you actually call `entrySet()` on both `HashMap`s, do the resulting sets look the same in the debugger?

Comment: From rockteboy's answer it seems that the `equals` method does depend on the `EntrySet` of the `HashMap`.  But it would be interesting to know if in your case the interator created by `entrySet().iterator()` yields different results (which seems weird if the keys and values are the same).  Like Paul Bellora said: it would really help the question to know how the `HashMap`'s are instantiated and populated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check this easily by looking at the source of [HashMap#Equals()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/AbstractMap.java#AbstractMap.equals%28java.lang.Object%29). The values are compared for non-null keys.

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == this)
        return true;

    if (!(o instanceof Map))
        return false;
    Map<K,V> m = (Map<K,V>) o;
    if (m.size() != size())
        return false;

    try {
        Iterator<Entry<K,V>> i = entrySet().iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            Entry<K,V> e = i.next();
            K key = e.getKey();
            V value = e.getValue();
            if (value == null) {
                if (!(m.get(key)==null && m.containsKey(key)))
                    return false;
            } else {
                if (!value.equals(m.get(key)))
                    return false;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassCastException unused) {
        return false;
    } catch (NullPointerException unused) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

**Edit:**

*Explanation:* An Entry is a `{key,value}` pair. HashMap maintains these `Entry`s in an EntrySet. Now to compare two maps: I can just iterate through all the `Entry`s and and keep comparing `Entry.value with anothermap.get(Entry.key)`. So, in essence the `equals()` of you value objects will matter when comparing maps.

Comment: How does this answer the question?